# One pixel of background shows in the table in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have been fighting this for a while, can't figure out why do I see one pixel of background show up in IE7 (other browsers work fine).

Here is a simple example, try it in IE7:

link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PstEk/

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
.test {
    border-width: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: red;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: blue;
}

.test th{
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: red;
    background-color: #fff5ee;
}

.test td {
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: red;
    background-color: #e1edf3;
}
</style>

<body>


<table class="test">
        <tr>
            <th>Test test</th>
            <th>Test test</th>
            <th>Test test</th>
            <th>Test test</th>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test test</td>
            <td>Test test</td>
            <td>Test test</td>
            <td >Test test </td>
        <tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Test test</td>
            <td>Test test</td>
            <td>Test test</td>
            <td>Test test</td>
        <tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't close the head tag?

Comment: Thanks so much, that was so stupid, spent half a day trying to figure it out!

Comment: @Christophe: You should make that an answer!

Comment: Omitting the `</head>` tag doesn't cause this problem, because it's optional, and omitting it is legal and valid! The validator complains because there's no `<title>` element, not because you forgot to put in some optional end tags.

Comment: @MrLister: He is using XHTML Strict and not closing the <tr> as in </tr> as pointed out by Jona. I think that is what was meant by Christophe. </head> is Optional?

Comment: @Jawad I don't see where he says he used XHTML.

Comment: @MrLister: Yup you are right. My bad. Is </head> Optional?

Comment: +1 All. Should have caught that. Need a break.

Comment: @Jawad Yes, in HTML all tags for `html`, `head` and `body` are optional, even the start tags! This is one of the reasons I prefer XHTML myself.

Comment: @MrLister: I thought it was so only in HTML5. HTML4.01 requires them!

Comment: @Jawad http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/elements.html is the official, formal list of HTML 4 elements, where the elements marked `O` have optional tags. And this has been the case since 1999!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE7 gets confused by the empty `<tr>` elements in your table. You meant `</tr>` instead of `<tr>`, but the way you're witten it now causes `<tr>` elements with no content to be inserted in the table. IE7 apparently gives empty `<tr>` elements a height of 1 pixel.

Answer (score 3):

While neither the `</head>` or the `</tr>` are required, I must point out that you should try using them, especially as I can see you are trying to use `</tr>` but instead are using `<tr>` again.

Do not underestimate the quirkiness of IE7 and use all closing tags.

Comment: Indeed. But in this case the problem is not caused by not using `</tr>` tags as such, but by the fact that there are now contentless `tr`s in the table! The problem is there even if you input all end tags. You can test this for yourself, by putting `<tr></tr>` in a table and see how IE7 behaves vs other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You havenot cloesd the `<tr>` elements.

Use a validator to spot these small annoying mistakes: http://validator.w3.org/

Edit: As mentioned in the other answers I was wrong, the closing `</tr>` is [not requiered](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.5), at least in HTML4. It just opens a new row.